# What is a machine state in Ethereum?

Tags: evm, state

Section 9.4.1. of [Ethereum paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) (Petersburg version 41c1837 — 2021-02-14), states that:

> The machine state ***μ*** is defined as the tuple (*g*,*pc*,**m**,*i*,**s**)
> which are the gas available, the program counter *pc* ∈ N_256, the memory content, the active number of words in memory (counting continuously from position 0), and the stack contents. The memory contents ***μ_m*** are series of zeros of size 2^256.

Further in [this documentation](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/evm/), a machine state is said to be prone to change from block to block according to a pre-defined set of rules and can execute arbitrary machine code. The specific rules of changing state from block to block are defined by the EVM.

Also in [the documentation](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/evm/), there is an external resource that illustrates machine state as part of volatile memory in the EVM.

So what is a machine state, what are pre-defined rules that can change machine state, and what it has to do with EVM?

Answer (score 0):

The machine state would be the environment where the contract runtime bytecode will be executed. A sort of virtual processor for the EVM's bytecode.

From the text "pre-defined rules" appears to mean a fork. Some forks had changed opcodes pricing affecting how gas consumption was evaluated and introduced newer opcodes modifying the machine state behavior.